# Laravel or php I have a week number of a month and a day, how can i get the date of these..?

Tags: php, laravel, date

i am used

```
date()    strtotime()
```

and so on... I need the date for a given week number of the month and day of the month.. 
Example., "3rd Week of the every month and Monday in every month for a year(Any one)"  I need these to conditions meet dates for a whole year..

Can you help me..?

Comment: We will help you after google has :)

Comment: how.. I need answer for my question...

Comment: Sorry, we won't give you an answer if you won't even try to answer it for yourself.

Comment: I tried a lot what i know in that functions..  Let you help me to solve...

Comment: Share the code with us of whatever you have tried.

Comment: strtotime(sprintf("%4dW%02d", 2016, 45));   It will providing for a year...  But i need for every month... Every month will be in below 4 or 5 weeks only...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for all mondays of a year:

```
$date = '2016-01-01';
$y = date('Y', strtotime("$date"));
$x = $y;
while(1){
    $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("next Monday $date"));
    $y = date('Y', strtotime("$date")); 
    if($x != $y) break;
        echo $date."<br/>"; 
}
```

Comment: Nice one... I think it will give every Monday date... Am i correct..?

Answer (score 1):

suppose you save month number in variable $month:

```
$firstDayOfmonth = mktime (0, 0, 0, $month, 1, date("Y"));
$threeweeksLater = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($firstDayOfmonth)) . " +3 week");
```

now suppose you have year number in variable $year and week number in $week:

```
$firstDayOfEveryWeek = mktime (0, 0, 0, $month, ($week-1)*7, $year);
$threeweeksLater = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($firstDayOfEveryWeek)) . " +3 days");
```

Comment: I need...  In every month, 4th week which is Monday then give that date in the year of 2016... Then what we want to do..?

Comment: set a foreach for $number from 1 to 12 then set $week = 4 and $year 2016. then the second code gives you the date

Comment: for($month = 1; $month <= 12; $month++){
            $firstDayOfEveryWeek = mktime (0, 0, 0, $month, (3-1)*7, 2016);
            echo date('Y-m-d', $firstDayOfEveryWeek)."//";
        }       Answer:-  2016-01-14//2016-02-14//2016-03-14//2016-04-14//2016-05-14//2016-06-14//2016-07-14//2016-08-14//2016-09-14//2016-10-14//2016-11-14//2016-12-14//

Comment: you should use "strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($firstDayOfEveryWeek)) . " +3 days");"

Comment: end set a foreach inside first foreach for $week to set from 1 to 4 to give date of every moundays inside month